# change the name of the First ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, controller, swift2, refactoring

When I create a new project in IoS, I get default ViewController class, called `ViewController`
I am using xcode7 and when I try changing the class name to ViewControllerSomething it tells me Xcode7 does not support that (yet).

**My question, how do I modify the name of the class manually?**

What I tried:

1. changed the file name
2. Changed the class name itself -> now I get a build warning

> 2016-01-28 13:17:41.877 TestPRJ[1400:491868] Unknown class
>   ViewControllerCategories in Interface Builder file.

3. Tried to modify any reference to ViewController in the Main.storyboard and in LaunchScreen.storyboard (opened as source code).
   Now I get a build error:

> /Users/itaymoav/Desktop/playworkspace/TestPRJ/TestPRJ/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard:
>   The document "LaunchScreen.storyboard" could not be opened. Could not
>   verify document content.

Answer (score 0):

After you manually rename the class:

1. Go to the storyboard which uses it (if it's a new project created from template it should be called Main.storyboard).
2. Make sure that scene is selected on the left panel (it should be called "View Controller Scene").
3. On the right panel go to the identity inspector (3rd icon) and under "Custom Class" select your new class name, it should be listed there.